# How to fix "Module 'timezonedb' already loaded" error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I know this can be an old problem but I googled for the solution and found nothing. Actually when I tested my site in localhost it is completely ok but when I move the site to my hosting site the error appears.

**Error is:**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'timezonedb' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Please can anyone help me.

I'm using codeigniter for backend.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Issue is due to use of older PHP version.
1) Go to cpanel
2) click on "select PHP Version" on "Software" section.
3) And choose your PHP version and set as current.
I hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its the conflict of timezone. please take a look in [This question][1]

https://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/397480-php-warning-module-timezonedb/

Sample code:

```
host added



date.timezone = "America/New_York"



To a php.ini file and



#SetEnv TZ America/New_York



to the .htaccess
```

or define your timezone like:

```
define('CFG_TIME_ZONE', 'America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 0):

I development mode it does not bother me at all that error. But in production it does. So i open index.php and set the evironment to "production".
That solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your index.php, please check the Code as follows

Find and replace  : error_reporting(-1); to error_reporting(0);
Find and replace  : ini_set('display_errors', 1); to ini_set('display_errors', 0);

worked for me